# How can I use lookup with two parameters?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

Hey so I have a large data set with 24,000 rows and about 20 columns. Amongst, the columns include Target company name, action, maxbid, value, round, and Acquiring firm. To give a little more detail, the action column contains several possible actions including bid, neg, contact, etc. I wrote a macro that filled the max bid column when a bid was higher than another bid in that round for a target.

I took this data set and created a pivot table that sorted the data by target company name and then round. The variables I want are the (max) max bid per round and the max bidder( found in the Acquiring firm column). How can i write a lookup function that can match the max bid value, target company, and round to pull out the value from the Acquiring firm column.

I will provide more detail if any of this was unclear. P.S. I tried writing an array formula like:

{=VLOOKUP(L3,IF([Workbook1]Sheet1!$B:$B=A3,[Workbook1]Sheet1!$A:$AI,"")*11,FALSE)}
but excel "ran out of resources"

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of three formulas:
  The max function to find the largest value.
  embedded in the match function to locate the row the number was found in.
  embedded in the Index function to return the value of the desired column, row combination.

```
=Index(B:B,Match(Max(A1:A1000), A:A, 0),1)  if A has the numbers and b has the name.
```